# CentOS 5.5 APIC issue on ESX 4.1 & ML115

Tags: centos, vmware-esx, hp-proliant

I've just installed vSphere 4.1 on an HP ProLiant ML115 G5 Quad-core and am trying to install CentOS 5.5 as a guest system.

However, when the guest boots up I get a calibrate_APIC_clock warning and a kernel panic message.

I've come across this [knowledge base article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1022250) on the vmware website which suggests moving the guest onto another Intel based host (!). Funnily enough I don't have a collection of spare host servers sitting around, so can anyone suggest another solution?

Alternatively, would installing an earlier version of CentOS get around this issue, or would a yum update put me back to square one?

How about BIOS settings, could anything be tweaked there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give `noapic` boot parameter for the VM, for starters.

BTW, the subject of your question says **ACPI** and the question itself **APIC**. I guess the correct one would be **APIC**? :-)

Comment: Whoops, I've corrected the typo, thanks. As for the boot option, I'll try tonight.

Comment: Unfortunately 'noapic' did not work.

Comment: Another parameter worth trying is `clock=pit`, then.